# Geting a null socket - android communiction with local host

Tags: java, android, sockets, localhost

Im running a server on my localhost written in Java, and Im trying to get my device to communicate with it. I've tried many ways and I've read lots of posts about it, but still didnt come up with a solution. That's what I've written:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String hostName = "10.0.2.2";
    int portNumber = 5667;
    private Socket echoSocket;


    private void runSecondThread() {

        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i("try", "enter try");
                    echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
                    Log.i("taggg", "echoSocket");

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    Log.i("error", "Don't know about host " + hostName);
                    System.exit(1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("error", "Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + hostName);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        runSecondThread();

    }
```

I figured out that my echoSocket is null. My device is connected to the same wi-fi as my PC.

Comment: Did you port forward? If you are trying to connect your android phone to your computer using wifi or 4g/3g for that fact you must have the public i.p. of the router and then you must go into your router settings and port forward it so the router knows where to direct all the traffic.

Comment: If echoSocket is null then wich exception did you catch?

Comment: @3kings: that has nothing to do with port forwarding as both devices are in the same WLAN.

Comment: @greenapps Just a thought.... I know when i developed my android app i needed to port forward even though i was connected to that wifi.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception, not from the try-catch, but from using the echoSocket.toString 
As for the port forwarding, I couldn't find it in my network, I found port mapping, but not forwarding

Comment: @Kickapoo can you pls post the code where you get the exception . Socket() always throws exception in case of failure . Trying catching generic Exception "Exception e" instead of catching UnKnownHost and IOException alone . Print the value of echoSocket after creating the socket() to check whether it returns null.